# zend pagination using DbSelect and DbTableSelect adapter

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm a beginner to zend framework...until now i was doing pagination by fetching all details from DB..my friend says that it is not a good way for pagination....
he give me the following reference from Zend site...now i have some doubts...
1.what is setRowCount?is it a field in the table?
2.what is item_counts and RowCount?
my DB name is sreejith.
my table name is employee.
the code is:

```
 $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($db->select()->from('posts'));
    $adapter->setRowCount(
    $db->select()
    ->from(
   'item_counts', array(Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect::ROW_COUNT_COLUMN => 'post_count')
    )
    );
    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP code pasted from:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.usage.html

That example is showing the ability to optimize how the total number of rows is calculated (needed to perform pagination, well to render the UI navigation at least).

As it says, "For example, if you keep track of the count of blog posts in a separate table, you could achieve a faster count query with the following setup:".

Look at the more simple examples passing a Zend_Db_Select to the factory... like: `Zend_Paginator::factory()` - That will probably be all you'll need.